# unicodedata is not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, openwrt, twisted.internet

I'm trying to install Twisted on a small board running a version of OpenWRT (chaos calmer). I'm running it step by step so I could track and install the missing packages on the device. Last error was:

```
ImportError: No module named unicodedata
```

I have installed all the packages offered for python by the vendor, tried find and grep in my Desktop's /usr/lib/python2.7/ also tried

```
python -v
```

on my desktop to find the module but haven't been able to locate it. Seems like it's an internal package.
How can I install unicodedata on the device?

Comment: I think you need the python-codecs package for openwrt. I think the version of Python that you have on there has been stripped of this module to save space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `unicodedata.so` is provided in the `python-codecs` package. A [x86_64 version](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/x86/64/packages/packages/python-codecs_2.7.9-6_x86_64.ipk) is available so presumably it's also available for other architectures.

You should be able to determine that with:

```
$ opkg search '*/unicodedata.so'
```

or possibly

```
$ opkg whatprovides '*/unicodedata.so'
```